# Similar functionality to getCurrentUser on Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-volley

Recently I played a little bit with the Parse.com SDK, and I liked their function **getCurrentUser()** that returns the current user.

So I was wondering how can I implement it and what is the necessary backend support to achieve such a thing.

I usually use the Volley library to make network calls.

**Edit**

I don't want to use the Parse.com in my app, however I want some thoughts on how it can be done because I found it a neat solution

Comment: you might store the user in a database

Comment: No, I want to make a CACHED request to check the current user and getCurrentUser() will be checking the cache if it is empty then make a network call.

Comment: @SafiS `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` already does that: it checks the local cache for a signed in user. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I don't want to use the Parse.com in my app, however I want some thoughts on how it can be done because I found it a neat solution